# Can I use a device of 100-240 V~, 50/60 Hz on a 720 W/1200 VA inverter?

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, inverter, ups

I am using an inverter back-up power solution device with 720 W/1200 VA output capacity.
I have connected a sound speaker with the below specs:

Input voltage: 100-240 V~, 50/60 Hz
Input current: 200 - 120 mA

Is it safe to plug in the speakers to use power from the inverter?

I have connected a laptop, a desktop computer, and a screen. I am concerned about the speaker overloading the inverter, as it is advised by the manufacturer not to use any other device apart from computers, routers, etc.

Comment: Don't ignore the advice given by the manufacturer. Of course, how you read that advice may be open to some interpretation.

Comment: @Andyaka, thanks, I am not good with electronics, I just wanted to know if the power required by the speaker will not damage the inverter/battery. The manual says not to use appliances like fridges, heaters, hairdryers etc  with the inverter, the speaker specifically was not mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worst case, 200mA at 240V is only 48VA.  It's a tiny load for a 1200VA inverter.

Comment: Thanks Simon, how did you figure out 48VA?

Comment: @teebo 200 mA is same as 0.2 A

Comment: @teebo P=V*I 240*0.200=68W, your inverter is rated to 700W. 68W is absolutely nothing compared to 700W. it does depend on how much power your computer is consuming though.

Comment: @teebo 0.200 x 240 = 48.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your input. I appreciate the time you've taken to help.